# Prove that the dual basis is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

**Q:** Suppose $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a basis of a vector space V over the field F . Let $e^1,\ldots,e^n\in$ $V^*$ be the linear functionals defined by $$ e^i(e_j) = \begin{cases} c, i=j \\
0, i\neq j \end{cases}$$ Then prove that the set $\{e^1,\ldots,e^n \}$ is linearly intependent .
**My approach:**
$\forall\,v:=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in V,a_1e^1(v)+\ldots+a_ne^n(v)=0$ 
In order to prove $\{e^1,\ldots,e^n \}$ is linearly independent I have to show that $a_1=\ldots=a_n=0$ . But here I confused how to show that . any hint or solution will be appreciated .
**Extra question:** I really confused why $e^1,\ldots,e^n$ defined like that $?$ Is it for make $e^i$ unique or something else .
I am newly introduce with dual space so sorry if my question is rudimentary.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Take $v=v_i$ to get $a_i=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why are you answering in the comment section?

Comment: $v_i=c_1e_1+\ldots+c_ne_n$ then $a_1e^1(v_i)+\ldots+a_ne^3(v_i)=0 \implies a_ie^i(v_i)=a_ic=0$ that make $a_i=0$ .Is it make the proof? And what about my extra question? Can you give me a intuitive way to understand it .And thanks @KaviRamaMurthy Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is somewhat unusual, but the $e^i$ are the *coordinate functions* for the basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ of $V$. That is, from any linear combination $x_1e_1+\cdots+x_ne_n$, where the $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are arbitrary scalars, the function $e^j$ extracts the coordinate $x_j$:
$$
  e^j(x_1e_1+\cdots+x_ne_n)=x_1e^j(e_1)+\cdots+x_ne^j(e_n)\\=x_1\cdot0+x_2\cdot0+\cdots+x_j\cdot1+\cdots+x_n\cdot0=x_j.
$$
Now to the question itself: here the linear combination is over the coordinate functions, so the result is an arbitrary linear function on $V$ with scalar values. To show that this is the null function only if all the coefficients are zero, you need to extract an individual coefficient $a_i$. The trick is quite similar to the above, only now it is not applying $e^j$, but *applying to $e_i$* what is needed:
$$
 (a_1e^1+\cdots+a_ne^n)(e_i)
=a_1e^1(e_i)+\cdots+a_ne^n(e_i)\\
=a_1\cdot0+\cdots+a_i\cdot1+\cdots+a_n\cdot0
=a_i.
$$
So it the linear form in the leftmost parentheses is zero, then certainly $a_i=0$, and this holds for every $i$.

Comment: Ok .what I understand if the linear combination over the coordinate functions isn't a null function then it's an arbitrary linear function on $V$ that result the coefficient $a_i ?$ .And thanks for clear me @Marc van Leeuwen Sir

Comment: @emonhossain What one needs to show is that when $f=a_1e^1+\cdots+a_ne^n$ is the null function (the zero vector in $E^*$) if follows that each of the coefficients $a_i$ must individually be zero (that is what linear independence means). This can be done by considering $f(e_i)$: on one hand it is zero because $f$ is the zero function, on the other hand $f(e_i)=a_i$ as I showed in the answer.